# How to display local images using flatlist?

Tags: image, react-native, flatlist

I want to make an offline app with aroud 200 images.I want to render those images using flatlist..Should i store those images in my project folder and create a json file with source to those image? Or whats the best way to do it

Comment: Since it is an offline app, I suggest adding those images to the assets folder, importing them into an array and then use that array for the flat list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dealing with a large number of images, then your images.js file will become difficult to maintain, in that case you could try using a plugin like https://github.com/dushaobindoudou/babel-plugin-require-all and then write a small script which will create an dictionary of your images like:

```
// prepareImages.js
const fs = require("fs");
const files = fs.readdirSync("./assets/images").filter(x => x.includes("png"));
const ex = "{\n" +
files.map(x => `"${x.split(".png")[0]}": require("./${x}"),`).join("\n") + "}";
const res = "export default " + ex;
fs.writeFileSync("./assets/images/index.js", res);
```